# Explicação sobre um comando JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho uma linha de comando no meu código JSP que não consigo entender tipo `StringUtils.isBlank`

Eu sei que é uma condição, o que não sei é o que está dentro. Segue parte do código:

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(historicoProcedimento.getRestricoes()) && StringUtils.isBlank(historicoProcedimento.getErros())){
```

Comment: Quer dizer então que de acordo com o código, se(historicoProcedimento.getRestricoes() e historicoProcedimento.getErros()) forem iguais a null ele vai entrar na função é isso?

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StringUtils.isBlank`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) retorna `true` se a string passada estiver em branco (`""`), contiver somente espaços (ou outros [caracteres considerados *whitespace*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html?is-external=true#isWhitespace%28char%29)), ou for `null`. Caso contrário, retorna `false`.

No seu código, você tem duas verificações dessas com um `&&` no meio (operador lógico AND). Ou seja, só vai entrar no `if` se ambas as condições forem verdadeiras.

Comment: _"estiver em branco"_ no caso desse método significa ser "" ou conter apenas _whitespace_, como por exemplo " "

Comment: Sim, acabei de atualizar após consultar a documentação

Comment: @Piovezan whitespace nesse caso inclui \n, \r, \t?

Comment: Tudo que [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html?is-external=true#isWhitespace(char)) retornar `true`.

Comment: Obrigado, acho que agora a resposta está precisa. Pra eu aprender a não me meter a responder coisa de linguagem que conheço superficialmente :)

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade foi até atencioso, pois se for levar ao pé da letra, é o caso típico para pesquisa ou consulta à documentação.